# Rightmost Til Stack?

Tags: crossword-clues

I'm rather confused by a clue and it's answer in the [USA Today crossword from January 19th, 2017](http://www.uclick.com/client/usat/usaon/2017/01/19/). The clue is 26-down.

Clue

> Rightmost til stack

Answer

> Ones

I had to look up that answer, and I still have no idea what it's about. How is that the correct answer for that clue?

Answer (score 5):

You appear to have made a typo.

> It's "till" stack, not "til" stack. A "till" is a cash register: the rightmost stack in a cash register drawer is the stack of one-dollar bills

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't think I've ever heard a register referred to as a 'till'. That makes some kind of sense then. The puzzle author clearly has a very different vocabulary than me, as I found that whole puzzle pretty obtuse compared to their usual fare.

Comment: @DCShannon: "till" is the British English term for it. Perhaps the author is British? That would explain the confusion.

Comment: I did indeed find a definition for 'till' matching this on Merriam Webster. Fourth sense, 1b: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/till